# Output Flexifield content as Excel file?

Tags: views, 6, entities, importing-exporting

I'm using Drupal 6 and [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) to create an extensible CCK content type for doing various measurements. The content type is composed of three flexifield fields -- "levels", "rooms" and "fixtures", all of which can have new rows added to them via the "Add another..." button (no min/max to the number of rows in each flexifield sub-type).

The "levels" flexifield sub-type has two fields: level name and total area. The "rooms" flexifield sub-type has three fields: length, width, area. The "fixtures" flexifield sub-type is irrelevant for this part of the project.

What I ultimately need to do is output the "rooms" data as a table, then export that as an XLS file (which is then used by some CAD software somewhere down the line). I've been trying to do this via Views UI and [Views Excel Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls), but I can't see to make the latter module conform to the Excel template I've been given:

Each room's row in Excel should look something like:

Block Name  |  Roomname  |  Imperial  |  Metric

"Block Name" is the same string for all rows; "Roomname" has to be the name of the room as defined in the "room" flexifield sub-type. The values entered in each room are all either Imperial or Metric as per an option on the main content type, but I'll need some way to populate the correct column based on whichever type of data's been entered, plus convert those values to the other system.

**Is Views UI (with Excel Export) the right way to go about this? If so, how do I interact with the "room" flexifield data insomuch that I can make each "Room" object a separate row in the Excel sheet?**

Many thanks. This is the last part of a huge project I've been working on for months and will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the CSV export provided by Views Bonus Pack? It's not true XLS, but does it need to be, as long as it opens in Excel and the data is correct?

Comment: The scope changed so that it's now CSV output; as a result, I think I'll end up using Views Bonus Pack. Thanks for the suggestion!